# Url subdomain rewriting/routing for existing application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting

I have been given a big working MVC application whose urls routes are all set. I have to add a subdomain entry for every possible url( which are many).

For example if my previous url for a page was localhost/home/register it would now become abc.localhost/home/register. I just want to fetch the value abc do some processing and call exactly the same controller and same action which was called before for localhost/home/register.

What would be the simplest approach to do this -URL rewriting or changing the routes. I am afraid changing the routes can be overly complicated as there are lot too many.

Comment: What have you tried? I think it will be better to show some codes. Because When you say "you just want to fetch  the value abc" is it from the view?

Comment: you can try in script through ajax sucess like window.location.href="somelink" to modify URL rewriting